# How to see the number of views of a post on mobile app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, views

I am using Stack Exchange App on my Android device. I am unable to see the number of views of any question. Can this be added to the mobile app?

Comment: Currently, the view count is not available in the Android app. For now, you can tap the question timestamp, and then hit "Open in browser" and visit the main site.